# OS X: Energy Efficient Web Service Calls in Background

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, nstimer, background-process

What is the most energy efficient way to call a web service in the background under OS X?

On iOS I would use the `fetch` background mode, but I haven't seen anything similar for OS X. Right now I have an `NSTimer` that fires every 25 minutes, but the schedule gets messed up if the device goes to sleep while the timer is waiting to fire.

Before I write some code to deal with sleep/wake I wanted to see if OS X has a better mechanism for my use case. I have not found anything in the docs.

Comment: Isn't using `cron` an option?

Comment: I'd only want the calls to the web service to happen if my App was open. It's my understanding that `cron` (or `launchd`now) would execute an App, but maybe I'm off base.

Comment: Would using events be an option? Have cron trigger an event if your app is open and have your app act upon that. I haven't used them myself so this advice might be off-course.

Comment: It seems like Apple has answered my question for the next version of OS X. I'll come back when the NDA is lifted and add an answer.